# Add new item to Realtime Database array

Tags: node.js, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-admin

How I could append an element to an array like that ?.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an item to an array structure like that, requires three steps:

1. Read the existing data.
2. Determine the key of the new item.
3. Write the new item.

In code that'd be something like:

```
const ref = admin.database().ref("javascript");
ref.once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  let numChildren = parseInt(snapshot.numChildren());
  ref.child(""+(numChildren+1)).set(4);
});
```

Note that this type of data structure is fairly non-idiomatic when it comes to Firebase, and I recommend reading:

- [Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2014/04/best-practices-arrays-in-firebase.html).

Comment: I thought so. Thank you.